# Proof of algebraic inequality with restrictions on the variables

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

How to prove the following inequality?
$$
(1-y)(x^y) + y(x^{y-1}) -1 > 0 \quad x>1,\quad  0 < y < 1
$$

Comment: Have you tried to fix $y$ and study $f_y(x) \dot = (1-y) x^y + y x^{y-1}-1$ as a function of $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using weighted AM-GM,

$$(1-y)x^y + yx^{y-1} \geqslant x^{y(1-y)}\cdot x^{(y-1)y}=1$$

As equality is not possible (requires $x^y = x^{y-1}$), the inequality is strict.

Comment: Great! Thanks!! Very helpful!